# How to get Apache karaf bundles information via web services (rest, soap)?

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I wonder is there any change get the information about bundles via web services (rest, soap)

I've found web console hawtio which runs on port 8181 and I see the list of bundles.
And I would like to get this info in json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hawtio uses [jolokia](https://jolokia.org/) for accessing the bundle list. The jolokia project provides web applications called *agents* serving a REST API. For quick experiments you can deploy the war [jolokia-war-unsecured](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jolokia/jolokia-war-unsecured/1.6.0/) into the hot deploy folder of a running karaf instance. This installs a A REST web service at e.g. `http://localhost/jolokia-war-unsecured/` which does not require any authentications.

In order to get the web application to run, the war feature is required. If it not running already you can install it via `feature:install war` within the karaf shell. With the `web:list` command you can always verify the deployed and running web applications:

```
karaf@root()> web:list
ID  | State       | Web-State   | Level | Web-ContextPath        | Name
----+-------------+-------------+-------+------------------------+------------------------------
100 | Active      | Deployed    | 80    | /jolokia-war-unsecured | jolokia-war-unsecured (1.6.0)`
```

With jolokia you can access any MBean of the Karaf JVM. To list the bundles the URL is for instance:

`http://localhost:8181/jolokia-war-unsecured/read/org.apache.karaf:type=bundles,name=root/`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Jens. Could you provide the endpoint to get a list of bundles?

Comment: Sorry, added the missing endpoint for listing the bundles to the answer above.

Comment: Jens, I tried the endpoint which you provided, but unfortunately, there is no bundle list in response. I got response: "error":"javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException : org.apache.karaf:type=bundle,name=root",
   "status":404 . Is this endpoint work for you?

Comment: Sorry, added the missing shell command `feature:install war` required when starting without war feature to enable war deployment.

Comment: I found out the valid endpoint - http://localhost:8181/jolokia-war-unsecured/read/org.apache.karaf:type=bundles,name=root/